# problem booting ubuntu 18.04/16.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, asus

i recently got a new computer asus n552vx, i installed ubuntu 18.04 via a usb drive (flashed with rufus in firt attempt and etcher in the second).
after i installation is completed, i reboot the system and boot ubuntu through grub but it goes to a black screen then it loads [this text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC1Sh.jpg)

after some digging i tried

> sudo apt install intel-microcode

then i updated my bios to the latest version asus bios Version 300 for asus n552vx. but the problem isn't solved. i installed ubuntu 16.04 and i had the same error. so i tried installing ubuntu 18.04 on my brother's laptop and it worked fine .. 
Any help please ?

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Installing nvidea drivers solved the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At your grub menu highlight Ubuntu.
Press `e`
Use your arrow keys to bring the cursor to the words `quiet splash`
Delete `quiet splash` and replace it with `nomodeset`
Type `Ctrl`+`x` or press `F10`
You now have access to limited graphics session.
Click on the Applications Overview (the small 9 dot grid icon in your launcher dock).
Type "drivers", or look for "Software & Updates".
In there select "Additional Drivers".
Change (or "install") your driver to a different selection, if available.
Apply the changes, and restart.